# Console Lib like IPython like Qt Console

Tags: python, .net, user-interface

I looking to Build a Gui App like IPython Qt Console in python or .net/mono.  Is there a similar Rich text Console Library available for python or .net/mono?

*prefer cross platform*

Comment: Well, there is PyQT http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: I am looking for existing gui component which can behave and support features like IPython console eg; embedding images.